# Comparar 2 ArrayList y obtener un tercero con las diferencias - Java

Tags: java, oracle, spring, arraylist

- Tengo una base de datos donde voy registrando todos los productos que van llegando desde un archivo, estos los voy guardando en un `ArrayList` para luego realizar las validaciones necesarias para luego insertarlos.
- Ahora bien, lo que necesito hacer es comparar el contenido de la base de datos vs el archivo, si en el archivo algún producto que ya existe, deja de venir,debo eliminarlo de la base de datos.
- En esta situación tengo 2 `ArrayList`, uno que tiene todo los productos de la base de datos, y en la otra los que vienen del archivo.
  *Mi idea es comparar los 2 `ArrayList` y de este obtener un tercero con las diferencias para luego poder saber que debo eliminar.

Código

```
ArrayList<String> listaA = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listaB = new ArrayList<String>();

listaA.add("uno");
listaA.add("dos");
listaA.add("tres");
listaA.add("cuatro");
listaA.add("cinco");

listaB.add("uno");
listaB.add("dos");
listaB.add("tres");
listaB.add("cuatro");
listaB.add("cinco");
listaB.add("seis");
listaB.add("siete");
listaB.add("ocho");
listaB.add("nueve");
listaB.add("diez");
//Aqui por ejemplo debería recuperar un tercer `ArrayList` con los valores:
//Seis, Siete, ocho, nueve,diez
//Los valores no necesariamente vendrán en el mismo orden en el archivo.
```

Esto lo tengo usando Java con `SpringBatch`, si alguno conoce otra forma usando por ejemplo JPA o `JdbcTemplate` seria útil.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes realizar una comparación entre elementos de la listaB que no se encuentren en listaA  y estos elementos agregarlos en una ArrayList:

```
    ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();   
    for (String element : listaB) { 
        if (!listaA.contains(element)) { 
            newList.add(element); 
        } 
    }   
    System.out.println(newList);
```

Salida:

```
 [seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez]
```

Otro método que sería similar al anterior sería simplemente remover los elementos de una lista que se contienen en otra mediante el uso del método [**removeAll()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
  listaB.removeAll(listaA);    
  System.out.println(listaB);
```

Salida:

```
[seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez]
```

Otro método sería realizando una intesección con streams, definiendo no incluir los que se encuentran en ambas listas:

```
    List<String> lista = listaB.stream().filter(f-> !listaA.contains(f)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(lista);
```

Salida:

```
[seis, siete, ocho, nueve, diez]
```

Answer (score 2):

Quizá ya tengas la respuesta con las anteriores. Pero simplificando un poco con Java 8 sería de la siguiente forma:

```
List<String> newList = listaB.stream().filter(p -> !listaA.contains(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(newList);
```

Donde se recorre la listaB buscando los valores de la listaA y agregando cada valor coincidente a una lista para retornarlo al final.

A diferencia de las demas respuestas es que puede lograr lo mismo en una sola linea.

Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para poder comparar un dos `ArrayList<>`, elemento por elemento, puedes usar el método `contains`, el cual es para saber si es que un elemento específico se encuentra dentro de una lista dada o no.

He creado un método utilizando los datos que haz dado en tu pregunta:

```java
public static ArrayList<String> encuentraDiferencias(ArrayList<String> listaA, 
    ArrayList<String> listaB) {
        for(String elemento : listaA){
            if(listaB.contains(elemento)){
                listaB.remove(elemento);
            }
        }
        return listaB.size()>0 ? listaB : null ;
}
```

Paso como parámetros las dos listas, recorre la `listaA`, y verifica que el elemento de turno se encuentra dentro de la `listaB`, si es que es así lo elimina, al terminar el recorrido por `listaA`, dentro de `listaB`, quedarán solo los elementos que son diferentes entre las dos listas.

Finalmente se retorna `listaB` modificada, como también puede que ambas listas sean iguales, he creado una validación adicional, en donde se comprueba que el tamaño del `ArrayList` a devolver, sea mayor a 0, de ser así retorna la lista, de lo contrario, retorna `null`.

---

Llamo al método anterior:

```
    if(encuentraDiferencias(listaA, listaB)!=null){
        for(String e : encuentraDiferencias(listaA, listaB)){//recorre ArrayList
            System.out.println(e);//imprime el elemento de turno
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("No existen elementos diferentes"); 
        //si es que la lista esta nula
    }
```

Como el método puede devolver `null`, es necesario comprobar de que tenga datos, si es que los tiene imprime cada elemento del `ArrayList`, de no ser así imprime el mensaje "No existen elementos diferentes".

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]